# getting ROI in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with OpenCV, and a part of my Project is the 3d Calibration, I'm doing that using the `cv::findChessboardCorners` function of OpenCV and that works great. My problem is that  I need to crop my image in based on the found part of the chessboard. Let's say that the found points of my chessboard corners are (`boardSize`( 2*3 )) :

```
     [384.87457, 275.93411; 402.59073, 305.37384; 420.99899, 335.61783; 366.1167, 277.35107; 
      384.15289, 308.0141; 402.59592, 339.44702; 346.16739, 279.11893; 364.19324, 310.56906;  
      383.36844, 343.98239; 324.71078, 281.3793; 343.24969, 313.93167;362.28644, 348.54108]
```

here is a part of my code that gives me the corners positions :

```
  if( (cv::findChessboardCorners(img,boardSize, imageCorners))){
    cv::drawChessboardCorners(img,boardSize,imageCorners,true);
    std::cout<<imageCorners[0] <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<imageCorners[((boardSize.height)*(boardSize.width))-1] <<std::endl;
    std::cout << imageCorners << std::endl;
    cv::Rect  myroi (imageCorners[0],imageCorners[((boardSize.height)*(boardSize.width))-1]);
    cv::imshow("Part ", img(myroi));

}
```

the problem is that I get only a rectangle of my region of interest.
[image]

As you can see above, the blue region is the region of my interest but the red rectangele is what I get. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have the coordinates of the 4 corners of the distorted chessboard. Use these to find the equations for the 4 lines that form the quadrilateral. For any given point, you will then be able to check if it lies between the top and bottom lines *and* between the left and right lines. If it does, mark it as 1 on a mask image, else 0. Use the mask image to cut out the distorted region.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to crop the image from the outer chessboard corners. You need to find MinX, MaxX, MinY and MaxY of your verteces list to get the smallest bounding ROI (**rectangle** of interest).

So your answer is simply:

```
TopLeft = (MinX, MinY)
BotRight = (MaxX, MaxY)

ROI = (TopLeft, BotRight)
```

Comment: I think he needs the parallelogram, not the bounding rectangle. So he would need a transformed rectangle as the ROI.